# Explaining something using second person point of view

Tags: word-choice

I am going to take the IELTS exam and if an examiner asks me:

"- Why exercise is important?"

Is it correct to answer:

"- It is important because it's good for your health"

or should i say:

"- It is important because it's good for people's health"

Comment: I hope he asks, "Why is exercise important?"  Either is fine.  The second person ("**your** health") is called the second person indeterminate.  It's understood in the context of the general question, that the pronoun refers to people in general.

Comment: In the speaking exam it's more important to expand on your answer than to give one short grammatical answer. You need to show you can express an opnion in some detail. It's not so much what is the "best" answer, but how you say it (pronunciation and fluency) and what you say (content and vocabulary).

Comment: Your proposed answer is too "clichè" and obvious. Say something like: *I believe exercise is one of the best ways to improve our health. Regular exercise not only keeps our bodies fit but it also lifts our mood.*

Answer (score 2):

With a little more context, the question is likely directed at you, someone else, etc.  You can often avoid having to use a pronoun in such cases, for example, "It is important because it improves health."  The answers assumes the same subject as the original question.

With a pronoun however, "one" is the correct pronoun to use.  I don't agree with Ily, you won't sound like a prat, and the use of "one" is not obnoxious.  Yes, "you" is very commonly used.

Comment: +1 for matching the absence of pronouns in the question with a similar absence in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

a.
If an IELTS examiner asks you "Why exercise is important?" you need to ask for her supervisor and get her replaced. She's asking direct questions as if they're indirect and shouldn't be administering the exam.

b.
The proper answer to the intended question *why is exercise important?* is *because it's good for your health* but only in informal English. On tests, the generic *you* should be replaced by the obnoxious *one's* (alt. *our*) and everything should generally be in full sentences just to show that you can phrase things that way.

So your first answer makes you sound like less of a prat but the second is better for your test and *It is important for one's health* is better yet.

Comment: That's good advice if the question was on paper, but it seems that this is a question asked in an interview, i.e. the "speaking" exam of IELTS, so a more relaxed and informal use of language is preferred. In any case, the candidate's answer is too short, they need to expand on their answer. It's not only about accuracy but also fluency and sounding natural.